# "using namespace" for Doxygen comments

Tags: namespaces, doxygen

All classes of my library are defined within a namespace. When I create a mainpage for Doxygen I have to explicitly use this namespace within comments to make Doxygen generate links. I would like to use something like "using namespace" for the whole comment block.

An example:

```
/**
* \mainpage My Library
*
* Use MyLibraryNamespace::MyClass to ...
*/
```

Here Doxygen automatically generates a link to the documentation of MyLibraryNamespace::MyClass.

```
/**
* \mainpage My Library
*
* Use MyClass to ...
*/
```

Here Doxygen does not generate a link to the documentation of MyLibraryNamespace::MyClass (as there might be multiple MyClass definitions in different namespaces I suppose). To ease the reading I would like to omit the namespace prefix in the comment. Is that possible without having to type `\ref MyLibraryNamespace::MyClass "MyClass"` every time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make this work for **one namespace** by putting your comment inside the namespace. This bugs me considerably as we have multiple nested namespaces and I hate having to use them in Doxygen comments.

```
namespace MyLibraryNamespace {
/**
* \mainpage My Library
*
* Use MyClass to ...
*/
};
```

**2016 Update from Markdown Perspective**

I'm using Doxygen for the C# docs for Realm (yes Doxygen handles the typical C# XML comment format too!). The Markdown main page uses the @ref to refer to namespaced classes:

```
The main classes you will use are:

- [Realm](@ref Realms.Realm)
- [RealmObject](@ref Realms.RealmObject)
- [RealmList](@ref Realms.RealmList)
- [Transaction](@ref Realms.Transaction)
```

You can see a rendered version [online here](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/api/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use alias like this:

`ALIASES += refmylib{1}="@ref MyLibraryNamespace::\1 \"\1\""`

This is an usage example:

`/**
* \mainpage My Library
*
* Use @refmylib{MyClass} to ...
*/`

And above will be processed by doxygen like this:

`/**
* \mainpage My Library
*
* Use @ref MyLibraryNamespace::MyClass "MyClass" to ...
*/`